# CORS multiple header in C# while accessing from different domain

Tags: c#, .net

I working on C# API side project, here one API is consumed or called from another API but here i am getting 'access-control-allow-origin' with multiple headers is there anyway to solve like if header exists we can create a new one and access from multiple domain.

Comment: You have to set the headers to enabling cors. Check link: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api

Comment: i think its http veb problem  check this link :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636611/how-does-access-control-allow-origin-header-work